# Is behavior of Javascript toFixed() consistent between browsers? (leading zero and rounding)

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I tried `document.write((2/3).toFixed(3));` in JSFiddle, and it came out as `0.667`. I am running Firefox on Windows, if that matters.

Will `(2/3).toFixed(3)` *always* give me `"0.667"`, and *never* `".667"` or `"0.666"` or `".666"` or anything else?
Are different browsers allowed to behave differently? Or may I rely on the presence of the leading zero, and rounding to nearest?

Comment: I would think yes, it is consistent. `toFixed` is a JS language feature, not a browser API. - https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `toFixed` is fully specified in [the JavaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tofixed) and locale is not considered as part of those steps. As such, its output is consistent between conforming implementations of JavaScript engines.

Comment: Actually, the leading zero is dictated by Steps 11(c)(ii)(1) "Let z be the String value consisting of f + 1 - k occurrences of the code unit 0x0030 (DIGIT ZERO)." but, yes, I see that it is dictated in the specification.

Comment: @RobertLozyniak - You're right that 11(a)(b) aren't the full story. I think it's either of them, depending on the value being handled (`0` for instance uses the first `"0"` from 11(a)(b) I believe). For your specific value you may be right. But it doesn't matter, it's well-defined.